# Blender 2.83 TLS and Blender 2.9, Can't view changes to quick smoke

Tags: smoke-simulation

I've looked all over and can't seem to find the answer, if there is one. I am making some candles and started using Quick Smoke. I'm curious so after I set up quick smoke I hit play and watch the beautiful smoke, very cool. So I make a change and change it to smoke + fire, I hit play or animation and I see pretty smoke but no fire. I have the smoke domain selected and change the cache type from Replay to Modular and then back to Replay. Poof there is now smoke and fire!! So now it seems like I have to do that for every change I make to the smoke and/or fire. I've tried refreshing the nodes and nothing.

What am I doing wrong, please help.